# Does this notation represent composition of two functions or multiplication?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

For a homework problem I am asked to find the orthonormal basis of a set of polynomials $ V = span \{ 1, x ,x^2 +  1 \}$ over the defined inner product " $ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 fgx^2 dx $ " (exact type set of the homework problem).

**Does the notiation of the inner product specified mean composition of $f, g = f(g(x))$ or the multiplication of $f, g = f(x) * g(x)$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself, if it meant composition of functions would $\langle f, g \rangle $ even be an inner product? I think the only thing this question can mean is that $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_o^1 f(x)g(x) x^2 dx.$$

The notation the question uses is a bit unhelpful though...

Comment: That's why I had added the background of the notion itself, I had figured the composition wouldn't have made sense in the context.

Comment: Though what do you make of the $x^2$? Is this to be $f(x) g(x)^2$?

Comment: @KDecker Brackets are usually only left out for linear maps. These are not, so you can be sure that it should be interpreted as $f(x)g(x)x^2$.

Comment: $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) \, g(x) \, x^2 \, dx$$
The factor $x^2$ is called *weight*.

Answer (score 1):

It is the multiplication.

Only the multiplication here conforms to the [(conjugate) symmetry property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) of an inner product, the composition does not. If $f=1$ and $g=x^2+1$, then you would have that $\int\limits_0^1 f(g(x))x^2 dx=\int\limits_0^1 x^2 dx\neq 2\int\limits_0^1 x^2 dx=\int\limits_0^1 g(f(x))x^2 dx$